# Efficient way to get max for the individual properties using linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have an IEnumerable list in which I want to get the highest value for a particular property from the list and then capture the same in the record and return the same.

Record :

```
public record EnvironmentOccupiedAndRelativeHumidityFields(
    double CoolingSetPointOccupied,
    double HeatingSetPointOccupied,
    double RelativeHumidityMax);
```

Code:

```
    public static EnvironmentOccupiedAndRelativeHumidityFields GetEnvironmentFields(IEnumerable<LibraryEnvironment> environments)
    {
        var occupiedAndHumidityFieldValues = environments
            .Select(l => new
            {
                coolingSetPointOccupied = l?.CoolingSetPointOccupied ?? 0D,
                heatingSetPointOccupied = l?.HeatingSetPointOccupied ?? 0D,
                relativeHumidityMax = l?.RelativeHumidityMax?? 0D
            }).ToList();
                                             
                                             

        return new(
            occupiedAndHumidityFieldValues.MaxBy(a => a.coolingSetPointOccupied),
            occupiedAndHumidityFieldValues.MaxBy(l => l.heatingSetPointOccupied),
            occupiedAndHumidityFieldValues.MaxBy(l => l.relativeHumidityMax)
        );
    }
```

I am trying to get the max of each field (coolingSetPointOccupied, heatingSetPointOccupied, relativeHumidityMax), which are nullable fields. If there is no value, I need to return the `0` but get an error in the return statement.

```
` cannot convert `Anonymous type is not assignable to parameter type double.`
```

Could anyone please let me know how to do the same?

Comment: Use `Max`, not `MaxBy`? `MaxBy` would return the instance of the anonymous type created by your `Select` projection which has the maximum value. `Max` returns the maximum value.

Comment: Just write simple `foreach` cycle - this would be faster.

Comment: Agree with @GuruStron.  What your code is doing is going through the data multiple times to find the maximum of each property.   using `foreach` means you would only go through the data once.  Whether that makes enough of  difference on your project to make it worthwhile, only you can tell, by benchmarking with some good data sts.

Comment: @Neil, do you mean foreach and compare individual items?

Comment: Write a foreach over all the datapoints and manually record the maximum value.

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current implementation will iterate the list 4 times:

1. Creating the `occupiedAndHumidityFieldValues` variable.
2. Calc max cooling
3. Calc max heating
4. Calc max humdity

The suggestion to simply loop over the collection once removes the multiple iterations. For a single loop, create a few variables to capture the max value and then compare/update for each loop.

For example:

```cs
int cooling = 0;
int heating = 0;
int humidity = 0;

foreach (LibraryEnvironment e in environments)
{
    if(e == null) continue;

    if(e.CoolingSetPointOccupied > cooling) {
        cooling = (int)e.CoolingSetPointOccupied;
    }

    if(e.HeatingSetPointOccupied > heating) {
        heating = (int)e.HeatingSetPointOccupied;
    }

    if(e.RelativeHumidityMax > humidity) {
        humidity = (int)e.RelativeHumidityMax;
    }

    // alternatively, use Math.Max
    cooling = Math.Max(cooling, e.CoolingSetPointOccupied ?? 0);
    heating = Math.Max(heating, e.HeatingSetPointOccupied ?? 0);
    humidity = Math.Max(humidity, e.RelativeHumidityMax ?? 0);
}
```

The above example is a single loop comparing the current value against the currently known max values. When the current value is greater than the known max value, it updates as-needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help but those all are nullable double fields

Comment: OK? So, just change the variables from ints to doubles ‍♀️